# Receiving Mail in Google Cloud (SMTP Relay-Mailjet) on EXIM

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-platform, vps, exim

I am using DirectAdmin on my server. I have configured EXIM. I can send e-mails, but I have not been able to receive e-mails. For example, when I try to send e-mail via example@gmail.com, I either get 550 verification required error return or I do not get any error. How can I solve this. I am using 2525 port on GCP.

My config below:

**exim.authenticators.post.conf**

```
mailjet_login:
driver = plaintext
public_name = LOGIN
hide client_send = :  apikey:client
```

**exim.routers.pre.conf**

```
send_via_mailjet:
driver = manualroute
domains = ! +local_domains
transport = mailjet_smtp
route_list = "* in-v3.mailjet.com::2525 byname"
condition = "${perl{check_limits}}"
host_find_failed = defer
no_more
```

**exim.transports.pre.conf**

```
mailjet_smtp:
driver = smtp
port = 2525
hosts = in-v3.mailjet.com
hosts_require_auth = $host_address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exim is primarily an SMTP MTA. It does not have any mechanism to "fetch" incoming mail from remote mailboxes - it listens on tcp port 25 (and maybe other ports) by default, and expects other SMTP servers to make inbound connections to deliver inbound mail.

Your configuration is for **outgoing** SMTP mail (from exim -> out) only.

In order to receive incoming mail with exim (Or indeed any other SMTP MTA), you will need to set the MX records in the DNS for your domain to point to your mail server, and then configure things with other services such that mail gets forwarded by SMTP to this domain. Your exim box will need to have a public IP and be reachable.

**OR**

If the other service doesn't support forwarding mail to you via SMTP, you will need some other program to retrieve mail from whatever mailbox. Something like fetchmail can retrieve email via IMAP/POP etc and drop it using SMTP to your exim server, if that's what you need to happen.